# comple json stringify

Tags: javascript, json

How do I convert

```
var blockobject= new Array();
blockobject[blockobject.length]={area:"1",markerid:[{position:"(34.689703991083334, 135.50275325775146)",title:"sometitle"},{position:"24.689703991083334, 125.50275325775146",title:"sometitle"}]};
```

into string
I Tried

```
var saveobject = JSON.stringify(blockobject,["markerid","area"]);
alert(saveobject);
```

It Returns

```
      [{"markerid":[{},{}],"area":"1"}]
```

I am using json2.js

Comment: What you try to get isn't clear. What's the JSON you want ?

Comment: I want to convert js object into string

Comment: Why not simply doing `var json=JSON.stringify(blockobject);` ?

Comment: This will return cyclic error

Comment: You object is not cyclic, I tried it and it works.

Comment: Don't use `new Array` when you can use the litteral `[]`

Comment: I think its come from googlemap api because I tried var json=JSON.stringify(blockobject) above indvidual it works